# polymer - alignment while using app-layout

Tags: css, polymer, flexbox, polymer-1.0

I am currently learning polymer and I am struggling with one of the example on the Polymer website. The example is this one : https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/app-layout#condensing-header.

My index.html is the same as the one in the Sample toolbars section, I have just replaced the body with the one in the Condensing Header.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- import latest release version of all components from polygit -->
    <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
    <link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
    <!-- sample-content included for demo purposes only -->
    <link rel="import" href="app-layout/demo/sample-content.html">

    <style is="custom-style">
      body {
        /* No margin on body so toolbar can span the screen */
        margin: 0;
      }
      app-toolbar {
        /* Toolbar is the main header, so give it some color */
        background-color: #1E88E5;
        font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: white;
        --app-toolbar-font-size: 24px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-header id="header" effects="waterfall" fixed condenses>
    <app-toolbar>
      <div title>Left</div>
      <div title>Title</div>
      <div title>Right</div>
    </app-toolbar>
    <paper-tabs selected="0" primary>
      <paper-tab>Food</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>Drink</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>Life</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
  </app-header>
  </body>
</html>
```

To make things easier: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7zand8IQw7YaS61J9jvC?p=preview)

In the Polymer tutorial, Left / Title / Right are resp. on the left, center and right of the header but in my version, they are all on the left. Any idea why ?

Thanks

Comment: i really can't find the any example in the page where they have used 3 `div`s. I just see some `paper-tabs` which are working fine in your example also. Can you post a link to the example also. If you wanna know how to place the divs instead of why then the answer is give `justify-content: space-between;` to your app-toolbar and that should do the trick.

Comment: I put 3 divs instead of this :
      <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
      <div title>Spork</div>
      <paper-icon-button icon="shopping-cart"></paper-icon-button>
For some reason plunker didnt show the icons so I used the divs.

Comment: You need to import `iron-icons` in order to see the icons and still  they will not be arranged as shown in the page because the page does not contain style that has been applied on the them.